# How to get over Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have some repeated hover states that runs a function to display some empty or filled icons (like you would see in some e-commerce websites with empty/filled carts). As practice, I wanted to create and put this into a custom hoverHooks component, w/ `useRef` and `useEffect` to run some `add/remove` eventListeners, likeso:

```
const ref = useRef(null)
function enter() {
  setHover(true)
}
function leave() {
  setHover(false)
}

useEffect(() => {
  ref.current.addEventListener('mouseenter',enter)
  ref.current.addEventListener('mouseleave', leave)
 return () => {
   ref.current.removeEventListener('mouseenter',enter)
   ref.current.removeEventListener('mouseleave',leave)
}
})
```

I did this so that the container holding my icons can just have the `ref={ref}` without me having to repeatedly write `onMouseEnter / onMouseLeave`. (I guess my refs are being repeated, but better three letters, and move my hover `state` to just one place.
Cannot read property '`removeEventListener`' of null, is what I get. I read the React 17 docs regarding this, under "potential issues." But their suggestion isn't working (capturing the mutable data by storing it into a variable).

```
useEffect(() => {
  const myRef = ref.current

  myRef.current.addEventListener('mouseenter',enter)
  myRef.current.addEventListener('mouseleave', leave)
 return () => {
   myRef.current.removeEventListener('mouseenter',enter)
   myRef.current.removeEventListener('mouseleave',leave)
}
})
```

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: `myRef` is the element, it won't have a `current` property. It should be `myRef.addEventListener` and `myRef.removeEventListener`

Comment: typo above! (myRef.removeEventListener) is right. Apologies for the typo!

Comment: Not sure of how you would use this hook. Could you give an example?

Comment: return [hover, ref], and then import this HoverHook.js file into where I would use it.
(maybe in my shoeCart.js)
import HoverHook from '../custom/HoverHook'
...
const [hover, ref] = HoverHook();
<div ref={ref}></div> for example.

Answer (score 5):

Is that what you are looking for?

```js
/* HOVER HOOK */

const useHover = ({ ref, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave }) => {

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (ref.current) {
    ref.current.addEventListener('mouseenter',onMouseEnter);
    ref.current.addEventListener('mouseleave',onMouseLeave);
  }
  return () => {
    ref.current.removeEventListener('mouseenter',onMouseEnter);
    ref.current.removeEventListener('mouseleave',onMouseLeave);
  };
},[ref,onMouseEnter,onMouseLeave]);
  
  return;

};

/* APP */

function App() {

  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  
  const onMouseEnter = () => console.log("ENTER");
  const onMouseLeave = () => console.log("LEAVE");
  
  useHover({ref,onMouseEnter,onMouseLeave});
  

  return(
    <div className="app" ref={ref}>
      Hover me
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.app {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: This is definitely similar to what I have, except that since we're using the function from the `ref`, we don't need to create those `onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave` functions.
so, in the component where we want to use the `hover state` and the `ref`,
`const [hovered, ref] = HoverHooks()`
then we can use the `hovered`, `ref` locally. I think this makes sense to me. I hope it does to everyone else

Comment: [This answer](https://github.com/LiveText97/eportfolio_insights/pull/257) helped me first but I also had a function, using `<ref>.current`, outside the effect hooks. For such methods, the `if (<ref>.current)` check mentioned in this answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

There is solution from YouTube:

```
const refHandle = useRef();

<i ref={refHandle}> 

// This is to revise the original  
refHandle.current.removeEventListener('touchstart', onStartTouchBegin, false);

// To the conditional format,
(ref.current)?.removeEventListener('touchstart', onStartTouchBegin, false);
```

Comment: This approach will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this recently in a test using jest and @testing-library/react. I was surprised none of automatic cleanup functions were handling this so I did some more digging and found an old [git-issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20080) which lead to [this post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#potential-issues) in the react documentation (note, this is in reference to React v17.0 Release Candidate). To quote:

> The problem is that `someRef.current` is mutable, so by the time the cleanup function runs, it may have been set to null. The solution is to capture any mutable values *inside* the effect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const instance = someRef.current;
  instance.someSetupMethod();
  return () => {
    instance.someCleanupMethod();
  };
});
```

Again, this was in regards to v17.0 release candidate so I don't suspect this to be a problem in later versions. I am using React v17.0.2 which leads me to believe this problem stems from our code and/or how we are using react-hooks with third-party libs.

I figured I'd share this information anyways in case someone runs across this problem and is looking for a solution that avoids memory leaks from not cleaning stranded event listeners. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `ref.current` in the cleanup function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  someRef.current.someSetupMethod();
  return () => {
    someRef.current.someCleanupMethod();
  };
});
```

Capture the `ref` inside the effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const instance = someRef.current;
  instance.someSetupMethod();
  return () => {
    instance.someCleanupMethod();
  };
});
```

Checkout [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#potential-issues) for more details:

> The problem is that someRef.current is mutable, so by the time the
> cleanup function runs, it may have been set to null. The solution is
> to capture any mutable values inside the effect: