# Getting Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null in react

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-ref

I viewed [How to get over Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022475/how-to-get-over-cannot-read-property-removeeventlistener-of-null-in-react) SO answer. But it didn't help me fix my issue. I have a component hierarchy as below:

```js
const CompA = () => {
  let containerRef = React.useRef(null);
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <CompB containerRef={containerRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

const CompB = (props) => {
  return <CompC containerRef={props.containerRef} />;
}

const CompC = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.containerRef.current.addEventListener("click", handleComponentClick);

    return (() => {
      props.containerRef.current.removeEventListener("click", handleComponentClick);
    })
  });

  const handleComponentClick = () => {
    alert("Component clicked");
  }
 
  return "test";
}
```

But I get a `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener')` error when I open the page.

Comment: Move `const handleComponentClick` above the useEffect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it doesn't matter.

Comment: It is possible that `props.containerRef.current` has changed between creating and trying to remove the eventlistener. I'm guessing here, but maybe you could put it in a variable (`const tmp = props.containerRef.current;`) and then use that variable when removing the eventlistener (`tmp.removeEventListener("click", handleComponentClick);`).

Comment: @EmilKarlsson Thanks, I will try this and post the outcome here. (Y)